# jQuery mobile multiple theme dependecies

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Below is mentioned in jQuery Mobile Docs

> If no theme swatch letter is set at all, the framework uses the "a"
>   swatch (black in the default theme) for headers and footers and the
>   "c" swatch (light gray in the default theme) for the page content to
>   maximize contrast between the both.
>
> All items in containers inherit the swatch from their parent.
>   Exceptions to this rule are the listdivider in listviews, the header
>   of nested list pages, and the button of split button lists. Those
>   default to "b" (blue in the default theme). Count bubbles default to
>   "c" (silver in the default theme).

My questions are

1) Why jquery mobile doesn't use a single theme. Why something from "a" something from "b" and "c"?

2) Because of it's using multiple theme it's not possible to make a single custom theme. For example if I make "g" for my custom design. Is there a way to force it to use single swatch "a" or "b" or "c" only so i can make custom theme using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. It does use a single theme!  The themes have multiple color
   profiles called **swatches**, which essentially delegate colors to
   elements.  jQuery defaults to those contrasting swatches because they work well together.  The
   excerpt you posted only comes into play if no theme swatch letter is
   set, so maybe that clears up some confusion.

   For instance, if you have multiple buttons, you can set the `data-theme`
   to any swatch you have defined in the theme to quickly choose between
   a color for that button.  See [button theming](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html).
2. You are making a single custom theme with ThemeRoller, it just has multiple color components.  (You can make that theme have one theme swatch, but I don't think you'd need to!)  Elements on the page will take on their parent's `data-theme` if no individual one is set.  If you just want one color swatch to be used on a page, just set that `data-theme=g` to the page div.

   ```
   e.g. <div data-role="page" data-theme="g">
          ... <!--everything is theme a unless otherwise specified-->
        </div>
   ```

I would suggest you to [check this out](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-themes.html), and read around the jQuery docs to get a feel for it.